# How can you sum these outputs in Python?

Tags: python

I made this code about a number and it's power. It will ask a number and it's power and show the output like a horizontal list.. Like 
Number = 2
Power = 3.... then output will be like=
    1
    2
    4
Number and power can be +/-.
But I want to sum those numbers like Sum = 7 after it shows 
1
2
4

I have no idea how to do it after the output. I am new to programming maybe that's why can't figure out this problem.

Here is the code in Python :

```
A =float(input("Number:")) 
B =float(input("Power:"))
print("Result of Powers:")
i = 0
while i < B:
    print(A**i)
    i = i + 1
while i >= B:
    print(A**i)
    i = i - 1
```

Comment: What is the second loop supposed to do?

Comment: The best way to learn stuff is to try it yourself

Comment: 1 loop for + and other for - powers

Comment: I will give you hint, you already have a variable "i" that you use to collect a sum "i = i + 1" you could introduce a new variable called "sum" that you use to collect the sum of what you are interested in "sum = sum + ?????"

Comment: So sum=0
and next sum will be sum=sum+(A**i)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another variable to store the sum
and to print values on the same line use `end=" "` argument in the `print` function

```
a = float(input("Number:")) 
b = int(input("Power:"))
sum = 0.0

i = 0

while b < 0:
    ans = a**i
    i = i - 1
    print(ans, end=" ")
    sum = sum + ans
    b += 1

while  b >= 0:
    ans = a**i
    i = i + 1
    print(ans, end=" ")
    sum = sum + ans
    b -= 1


print("\nSum = " + str(sum))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify this with numpy as follows

```
import numpy as np

A =float(input("Number:")) 
B =int(input("Power:"))
print("Result of Powers:")

power = np.arange(B)

power_result = A ** power
sum_result = np.sum(power_result)

print(power_result)
print(sum_result)
```

I made B into an int, since I guess it makes sense. Have a look into the [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/) to see, what individual functions do.

Comment: I will check it out.Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve with the second loop. This works:

```
A =float(input("Number:")) 
B =float(input("Power:"))
print("Result of Powers:")
i = 0
n_sum = 0
while i < B:
    n_sum += A**i
    print(A**i)
    i = i + 1
while i >= B:
    n_sum += A**i
    print(A**i)
    i = i - 1
print(n_sum)
```

Comment: Now it works. Now I get what your second while was for

Comment: The prob was that I was thinking about another loop to just sum these numbers but never thought about sum in those 2 loops